# (SQL Athena) Get business days between two dates

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I have my table like this:

```
WITH my_table (start_date, end_date) AS (
    values 
    ('2021-10-01','2021-10-05'),
    ('2021-10-01','2021-10-03'),
    ('2021-10-02','2021-10-10'),
    ('2021-10-02','2021-10-08'),
    ('2021-10-02','2021-10-05')
) 
SELECT *
FROM my_table
```

| start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-10-01 | 2021-10-01 |
| 2021-10-01 | 2021-10-01 |
| 2021-10-02 | 2021-10-10 |
| 2021-10-02 | 2021-10-08 |
| 2021-10-02 | 2021-10-05 |

I want to count working days (from Monday to Friday).
Desired table should look like this:

| start_date | end_date | business_days |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-01 | 2021-10-05 | 3 |
| 2021-10-01 | 2021-10-03 | 1 |
| 2021-10-02 | 2021-10-10 | 5 |
| 2021-10-02 | 2021-10-08 | 5 |
| 2021-10-02 | 2021-10-05 | 2 |

Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to count days from Monday to Friday

You can generate sequence between the dates and use [`day_of_week`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html?highlight=day_of_week#day_of_week) to filter out the not needed days ([see array functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html)):

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset(start_date, end_date) AS (
 values     (date '2021-10-01', date '2021-10-05'),
    (date '2021-10-01', date '2021-10-03'),
    (date '2021-10-02', date '2021-10-10'),
    (date '2021-10-02', date '2021-10-08'),
    (date '2021-10-02', date '2021-10-05')
)

-- query
select start_date,
       end_date,
       cardinality(filter(
               sequence(start_date, end_date, interval '1' day),
                d -> day_of_week(d) not in (6,7)
           )) business_days
from dataset;
```

Output:

| start_date | end_date | business_days |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-01 | 2021-10-05 | 3 |
| 2021-10-01 | 2021-10-03 | 1 |
| 2021-10-02 | 2021-10-10 | 5 |
| 2021-10-02 | 2021-10-08 | 5 |
| 2021-10-02 | 2021-10-05 | 2 |

> I want to count working days

But this is much harder and not sure that it can be done without separate "dictionary" table which will cover holidays and such